# Does the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\big[1 + n\ln\big(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\big) \big]$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As title says, does the following series converge? $$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\big[1 + n\ln\big(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\big) \big]$$

It is supposed to converge but I don't know how.

My attempt:

$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\big[1 + n\ln\big(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\big) \big] = \sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n,$$
where

\begin{align}
a_n &= \big[1 + n\ln\big(\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\big) \big] \\
    &= 1 + n\big[\ln(2n-1) - \ln(2n+1)\big]. 
\end{align}

I couldn't come up with any good convergence tests and started listing out a few terms:

$a_1 = 1 + 1\ln(1) - 1\ln(3)$,

$a_2 = 1 + 2\ln(3) - 2\ln(5)$,

$a_3 = 1 + 3\ln(5) -3\ln(7)$,

and so on.

Since some terms cancel, I think for the $N$-th partial sum, we have:

\begin{align}
\sum_{1}^{N}a_n &= N + \ln(2N-1) - N\ln(2N+1) \\
                &= N + \ln\frac{2N-1}{(2N+1)^N}
\end{align}
At this point, I can only see divergence as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly test for convergence in this case?

Comment: I would apply the integral test on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg[n\ln\Big(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\Big)-1\bigg]$.

Comment: Wouldn’t the constant term 1 be a problem when applying the integral test?

Comment: No. The function $f(x)=x\ln\Big(\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\Big)-1$ is positive and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$

Comment: FYI: $$\int \Big[x\ln\Big(\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\Big)-1\Big]dx=\frac{1}{2}x\Big[x\ln\Big(\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\Big)-1\Big]+\frac{1}{8}\ln\Big(\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\Big)+C$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling why is there a sign change on 1? Is this important?

Comment: I multiplied what you called $a_n$ in your post by $-1$ in order to get my summand. This ensures that we have a positive decreasing sequence which is a requirement to use integral test. Once we show that $\sum-a_n$ converges then the convergence of $\sum a_n$ is immediate.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Oh, sorry I didn’t see the fraction was also reversed. I will try this, thank you!

Comment: FYI If you want to evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x\Big[x\ln\Big(\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\Big)-1\Big]$ I suggest you perform the substitution $u=\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}$ and note $u\rightarrow 1^+$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @js9 You may obtain the upper/lower bounds for $a_n$.

Comment: There's even an [exact evaluation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3019050) of this sum. (And the question about convergence is asked already, too.)

Comment: @metamorphy, yes actually they both do. Sorry I couldn't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(\log\frac{1-\frac x2}{1+\frac x2}\right)+1$$

Then

$$f(x)=\frac1x\log(1-\frac x2)-\frac1x\log(1+\frac x2)+1$$

Use Taylor's formula:

$$\log(1-x)=-x-\frac12x^2-\frac13x^3+O(x^4)$$

$$f(x)=(-\frac12-\frac18x-\frac1{24}x^2+O(x^3))-(\frac12-\frac18x+\frac1{24}x^2+O(x^3))+1$$

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{12}x^2+O(x^3)$$

Hence $1+n\log \frac{2n-1}{2n+1}=-\frac{1}{12n^2}+O(\frac 1{n^3})$

And your series is convergent.