# Is this series convergent? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n\ln\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}-1\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this infinite series convergent or not? How to solve it?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(n\ln\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}-1\right)$$

**Context:** I've learnt infinite series for a couple of weeks but still not familiar with how to solve those questions. I've tried to use Taylor to transform it but still no result.

Can anybody help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: using $x=\frac{1}{2n}$ in $\frac{1}{2x}\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}=1+\frac13x^2+\cdots$ will get you an asymptotic form for the $n$th term.

Comment: thanks!I think I get how to solve it in general.but I'm not quite sure about your second equation.maybe some Taylor stuff that I haven't get yet?

Comment: Use $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3-\cdots$ for $|x|<1$ twice in $\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: ohhhh amazing interesting!but the next we may add an infinite number of convergent series.is that still converges?since we have infinite ones. or can I just write it into the form of o(..)?is that reasonable?

Comment: That the $n$th term is $O(1/n^2)$ is enough to use a [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_series) [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test#Statement).

Comment: ..almost forgot. got it. thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019050/find-sum-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-n-cdot-ln-frac2n12n-1-1?noredirect=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use limit comparison test with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$, with some work (L'Hopital rule or manipulations) you get
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n\ln{\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)}-1}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{1}{12},
$$
since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, the series in question will also converge.

Comment: thanks but why can we use L'Hopital since the denominator is 0 and numerator is infinite?

Comment: @berryx $\lim n\ln{\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)} = 1$, you can see this by using the fundamental limit of the exponential

Comment: :thanks.I think I got it!

Answer (score 1):

Using $\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}=1+\frac2{2n-1}$ and $x-\frac{x^2}2<\log(1+x)<x-\frac {x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3$ for $0<x<1,$ then using $x=\frac2{2n-1}$ then $$x-\frac{x^2}2=\frac{2}{2n-1}-\frac{2}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{4n-4}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac1n\left(1-\frac1{(2n-1)^2}\right)$$ and thus:

$$-\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}<n\log\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}-1<\frac{2n+3}{3(2n-1)^3}<\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$$ when $n\geq 2$ and thus $2n+3<3(2n-1).$

Answer (score 1):

(Direct) Comparison test:
$$n\ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)-1<\frac1{n^2}$$
$$2n+1<e^{(\frac1n+\frac1{n^3})}(2n-1)$$
It is enough to show that
$$2n+1<(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^3}+\frac1{2n^2})(2n-1)$$
which is true when $n>\frac23.$